# How to put one user control into another user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

suppose i have two user control. usercontrolA and usercontrolB. how to include usercontrolB into usercontrolA. also please tell me how to read controls value of usercontrolB from usercontrolA and also from page. looking for details discussion. thanks

Comment: User Control are meant as standalone components and it's not really ideal to create dependencies between them. Could you explain what it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

May be below can help you

In Control A

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/ControlB.ascx" TagName="ControlB" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<uc:ControlB ID="myControlB" runat="server" />
```

In Control A.ascx.cs

```
string userName=myControlB.UserNameTextBox.Text;
```

In User ControlB.ascx.cs have some properties like

```
public TextBox UserNameTextBox
{
  get {return this.txtUserName;}
}
```

Comment: have u tested it. i did this and i got compilation error. please review ur code in IDE and then get back. thanks

Comment: Missed out get statement. can you check now. what compilation error are you getting?